# Bind PreferenceScreen into Composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Using androidx libraries, I built the UI entirely with Jetpack Compose, together with Navigation.

Following the official tutorials, I made a Preference Screen `R.xml.preference_screen` using [`PreferenceScreen`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceScreen) as the root of my hierarchy and a fragment that loads the xml resource as follows:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_screen, rootKey)
    }
}
```

In order to bind the fragment into a Composable, following [Android Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose#fragments-in-compose), I created the layout for the fragment container:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.perissf.SettingsFragment" />
```

But now I don't know how to bind this Fragment into a Composable. I have tried this

```
fun SettingsComposable(modifier: Modifier) {
    AndroidViewBinding(SettingsFragmentContainerBinding::inflate) {
        val myFragment = fragmentContainerView.getFragment<SettingsFragment>()
    }
}
```

And I don't think it's the right solution (what should I do with `myFragment`?), moreover this throws:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: FragmentContainerView must be within a
> FragmentActivity to use
> android:name="com.perissf.SettingsFragment"

Comment: So does your activity extend `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake well, no, I don't have an Activity yet. I only have Composables so far in my project. And my SettingsFragment which is a [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat)

Comment: All composables are eventually in an activity